# How can React/NextJS handle routing and images if the path contains no clues about type of data?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, next.js

I'm evaluating and learing React and NextJS for a future project, and have only scratched the surface so far. But I have already come across two potential problems. And when asking people more knowledgable in React they couldn't really give any clear answers.

Background:
We use a CMS that contains both structural data (returned as JSON) and images (returned as binary data). And the structural data can be of different types, like a news article, a debate article, a company information article etc.

Now, **it is not possible to detect what kind of data it is by just looking at the URL**. Image URLs doesn't end with .jpg, and news article URLs doesn't start with /news/, for example. For the purpose of this question, one can assume that the URL www.oursite.com/12345 can represent any of these kinds (ie an image, a debate article, a news article etc).

When I read about routing in react, all examples seems to revolve around being able to use the start of the path to detect what component to render. But we can't do that in our case. **Is there any way to route the rendering based on the json response?**

**Also, how should we handle the images?** If the URL www.oursite.com/12345 happens to represent an image, then the backend CMS API will return the raw binary data, and that should be returned to the browser as is.

**We can't append any kind of request parameters to the images**, because we need to handle direct requests to these images (for example, someone has an old newsletter saved as a HTML file on his computer, and it references www.oursite.com/12345 in an img tag.

Regards
/Jimi

Comment: Oh long desc. Is it worth to read?

Comment: @Blasanka Quick summary: How to route strictly based on json data from backend? And how to handle images if we don't know they are images before we fetch them from the backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using Clean URLs with Route Masking feature of next.js.

Lets have a look at the following code block:

```js
const PostLink = (props) => (
  <li>
    <Link as={`/p/${props.id}`} href={`/post?title=${props.title}`}>
      <a>{props.title}</a>
    </Link>
  </li>
)
```

In the  element, we have used another prop called “as”. That's the URL which we need to show on the browser. The URL your app sees is mentioned in the “href” prop.

This masking might help in your case. In `as` prop we can have our data related with url.

For more details. Follow the link.

https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/clean-urls-with-route-masking

Comment: Thanks! We ended up doing exactly this. Although it only solved things on the client. I forgot to mention SSR in my question, but we found a solution for that too. A custom nextjs server, that fetches the json data and analyzes it to determin what page to render.

Comment: The only problem we're having with that approach is that  we need to have an ugly "exclude" list of url patterns that we should ignore (like "/_next/*", "/static/*, "/babel/* etc), since there is no pattern that matches all URL's that should be fetched from the backend that doesn't also match URL's that should be ignored. It would be a cleaner solution if we could let next handle the request first, and only if it failed to find any file/page/etc, then our middleware could take over. But I haven't found a way to do that just yet...

Comment: @j5423951 would love to see an example. I have the same problem